# UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password) returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I took over a project from a colleague, and he used a custom `IdentityUser` to add new fields to the `IdentityUser`.

He added a new password field, which is storing the password as plain string, not encrypted.

When i try to log in the new created user, my `UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password)` is always returning `null`.

When i try to login, with no errors, except that it goes to ***Invalid username or password***.

I have checked the database, and both information is correct.

How can I find out the real problem?

Comment: Storing the password as plain string?! Well, the person who wrote that needs finding and giving a good telling off. I didn't think anyone was doing such awful things these days. :(

Comment: I hope you had to take over the project because that colleague was fired? Anyway, if they didn't override the UserManager, it'll still perform the default job of hashing the password and comparing that with the hashed password in the database.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster, hashing the password was the solution. Thanks very much